# Drupal: show content in fancy way

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, cck

I have a Drupal site on which users can enter CCK content by uploading docs to content. CCK has title, body, and a set of attached documents and I would like to show the nodes (using views) in a fancy and sexy way to make the application really appealing (I need to make customer happy).
I know that this is a little difficult because document management is not a sexy argument, but I would like to find an original way to show content. Do you know which module(s) can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but here are a few ideas off the top of my head...

If you have thumbnails of the documents, you could display a [Cover Flow effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_Flow), using the [Views Slideshow: ImageFlow module](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_imageflow).

Or you could use Views to output a list and theme the list with something like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [QuickSand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly ?  I think that a good design with some nice icons etc... would be a nice starter to make it 'sexy'...

Answer (score 1):

I've used this module [jCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) on a Drupal site to make my content look more interesting. It works best if you have image fields but you can do some simple styling to make a textual view look pretty.

+1 to Matt V. for Isotope, it's what I've been looking for another of my projects! I'd up-vote if i had enough rep.